# Select rows from one data frame where all column values exist in the second data frame

Tags: r

I would like to select the rows from `ds1` that all of its column values exist in the second data frame `ds2`. I found this long way to do it, but for sure exist a built-in function that simplify the process.

```
ds1 = data.frame(x=c(0,3,2,4,5), y=c(6,7,8,9,10), z=c(11,12,13,14,16))
ds2 = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(6,7,8,9,10), z=c(11,12,13,14,15))
```

Because the values `ds1$x[1]` and `ds1$z[5]` don't exist in columns: `ds2$x` and `ds2$z` respectively, such rows should not be considered, so final result should be:

```
  x y  z
2 3 7 12
3 2 8 13
4 4 9 14
```

therefore the rows: `ds1[2:4,]`, I found this long way:

```
result <- matrix(NA, nrow(ds1), ncol(ds1))
count = 1
for (i in names(ds2)) {
    result[,count] <- ds1[, i] %in% ds2[, i]
    count <- count + 1
}

rows = rep(NA, nrow(ds1))
for (i in 1:length(rows)) {
   rows[i] = all(result[i,])
}
# Finally:
ds1[rows,]
```

I suspect it should exist a simpler way using some built-in function combination, I google it, but I didn't found any similar case.

**Note**: I was playing with [merge](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.9.8/topics/merge), for example: `merge(ds1,ds2)`:

```
> merge(ds1, ds2)
  x y  z
1 4 9 14
```

, but because the column elements can be at different rows like in: `ds1$x[2] == ds2$x[3]`, and `ds1x[3] == ds2$x[2]`, it does not work and I do not know how to set the additional merge arguments in order to get the expected result.

Comment: `%in%` as shown below is preferable, but you could do it with a couple of joins - `merge(merge(ds1, ds2["x"]), ds2["z"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `%in%` and `&` syntax to express this very simply and concisely:

```
ds1[ds1$x %in% ds2$x & ds1$z %in% ds2$z,]
```

> ```
>   x y  z
> 2 3 7 12
> 3 2 8 13
> 4 4 9 14
> ```

This tells R "Select the rows of `ds1` where the following 2 conditions are true:

1. The value of `ds1$x` is found somewhere in `ds2$x`
2. Likewise for `ds1$z`"

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R, this is just a toy example, in my real problem I have around 52 columns, so I still need a for-loop.

Comment: @DavidLeal Sure, but wouldn't it still be faster to do it this way than with a for-loop? If you post an example that's more representative of the data I can show you. This can scale up to any number of columns and for loops are exponentially slower than vectorized solutions, so the more columns you have the less you want to use a for loop.

Comment: I got your point, your recommendation is using a solution like: `ds1[ds1$x1 %in% ds2$x1 & ds1$x2 %in% ds2$x2 & ds1$x3 %in% ds2$x3 ...& ds1$xn %in% ds2$xn,] ` (up to n variables) will scale better than using a for-loop solution. It will be a large statement for my case but less time consuming.